# stack notification received from parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to stack multiple received notification from parse,when received notification is more than 1 notify and display to user in one notification. I searched so much but i can not find the right solution. is that possible anyway?

Comment: Basically, you want to combine multiple unread notifications into one?

Comment: @NewToEarth yes, such as telegram or whats app application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a custome PushReceiver, so according to Parse docs you declare receiver in the manifest

```
<receiver
    <!-- Put here path to a class that will handle pushes -->
    android:name="com.domain.ReceiverClass"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE"/>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in this PushReceiver class you implement all needed logic concerning displaying of pushes

```
public class PushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Don't call super.onPushReceive!
        JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra(KEY_PUSH_DATA));
        //Here is how you obtain data
        String alert = pushData.optString("alert", "Notification received.");
        //Any manipulations with stacking go here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**. So everything depends on your requirements. You can for example just accumulate notifications in the receiver and schedule AlarmManager to wake up after 5 mins. Pass current number of notificaitons as an extra and then check if new pushes arrived. If so - wait for the next alarm, if not - show everything.

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        );
        JSONArray stacked = new JSONArray(prefs.getString(KEY_STACKED, ""));
        stacked.put(alert);
        prefs.edit().putString(KEY_STACKED, stacked.toString()).apply();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ActualProcessor.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNT, stacked.length());
        PendingIntent receiver = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, CODE, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5),
                receiver
        );
```

Comment: i did that.but  `onPushReceive` receive one notification and i can just change each notification's implementation ,not multiple notifications together . i do not know how to access multiple notifications in `onPushReceive`.

Comment: Received notification -> get shared preferences -> check if there are saved notifications there -> if there are: get them, remove from preferences, show all notifications -> if there not: put current notification into preferences

Comment: suppose i receive  4 notifications together .by your solution , after second notification i should will show 2 first notifications and the rest of notifications display in groups which contain 2 notifications.i mean how can i find out the number of received notifications?

Comment: It depends on how long interval should be. You can schedule AlarmManager to check if new pushes appeared after 5 mins from receiving the first one.

Comment: what is ActualProcessor?

Comment: @serenei BroadcastReceiver implementation (you should create this class) that will get intent sent by AlarmManager and check if new pushes arrived, show notification

Comment: ,is there any sample code to have all these feature in it? I'm new in android and  should ask a lot of question to write this code,if you know any sample code in `github` please give me to get the basic step of this procedure.

Comment: @serenei I don't think you will find example code somewhere. What you need in you receiver (ActualProcessor) is to extract JSONArray that you populate in your ParseReceiver from prefs, compare its length with the one passed as Intent extra and make appropriate decision - show notification or not